# Newtonsoft.JSON Mono Float Deserialize Exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, mono, json.net, raspbian

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON String in a JObject wit Newtosoft.Json under Raspbian with mono. But it cannot deserialize Float.

```
Dim myStationJSON As String
myStationJSON = myWC.DownloadString("https://api.netatmo.com/api/getstationsdata?access_token=" & myToken.Token.access_token)

Dim myJSON As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
Dim myStationName As String = ""
Dim opts As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
opts.FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Double
myJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myStationJSON, opts)
```

I'm getting this Exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Input string '-0.2' is not a valid number. Path 'body.devices[0].modules[0].dashboard_data.Temperature', line 1, position 329.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber (ReadType readType) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteToken (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Boolean writeChildren, Boolean writeDateConstructorAsDate, Boolean writeComments) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.WriteToken (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Boolean writeChildren, Boolean writeDateConstructorAsDate, Boolean writeComments) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x00000] in :0
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x00000] in :0

JSON:

```
{
"body": {
    "devices": [
        {
            "_id": "XXX",
            "cipher_id": "enc:16:XXX",
            "last_status_store": 1483489982,
            "modules": [
                {
                    "_id": "XXX",
                    "type": "NAModule1",
                    "last_message": 1483489978,
                    "last_seen": 1483489933,
                    "dashboard_data": {
                        "time_utc": 1483489933,
                        "Temperature": -0.2,
                        "temp_trend": "stable",
                        "Humidity": 89,
                        "date_max_temp": 1483489933,
                        "date_min_temp": 1483484498,
                        "min_temp": -0.4,
                        "max_temp": -0.2
                    },
                    "data_type": [
                        "Temperature",
                        "Humidity"
                    ],
                    "module_name": "Außen",
                    "last_setup": 1384606905,
                    "battery_vp": 5870,
                    "battery_percent": 95,
                    "rf_status": 81,
                    "firmware": 43
                },
                {
                    "_id": "XXXX",
                    "type": "NAModule4",
                    "last_message": 1483489978,
                    "last_seen": 1483489933,
                    "dashboard_data": {
                        "time_utc": 1483489933,
                        "Temperature": 21.7,
                        "temp_trend": "stable",
                        "Humidity": 38,
                        "CO2": 1139,
                        "date_max_temp": 1483489933,
                        "date_min_temp": 1483485422,
                        "min_temp": 21.5,
                        "max_temp": 21.7
                    },
                    "data_type": [
                        "Temperature",
                        "CO2",
                        "Humidity"
                    ],
                    "module_name": "Schlafzimmer",
                    "last_setup": 1414704430,
                    "battery_vp": 4876,
                    "battery_percent": 38,
                    "rf_status": 79,
                    "firmware": 43
                }
            ],
            "place": {
                "altitude": 210,
                "city": "XXX",
                "country": "DE",
                "timezone": "Europe/XXX",
                "location": [
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "station_name": "XXX",
            "type": "NAMain",
            "dashboard_data": {
                "AbsolutePressure": 993.7,
                "time_utc": 1483489969,
                "Noise": 51,
                "Temperature": 21.8,
                "temp_trend": "stable",
                "Humidity": 44,
                "Pressure": 1021.2,
                "pressure_trend": "down",
                "CO2": 1069,
                "date_max_temp": 1483484530,
                "date_min_temp": 1483485740,
                "min_temp": 21.6,
                "max_temp": 21.8
            },
            "data_type": [
                "Temperature",
                "CO2",
                "Humidity",
                "Noise",
                "Pressure"
            ],
            "co2_calibrating": false,
            "date_setup": 1384607020,
            "last_setup": 1384607020,
            "module_name": "Wohnzimmer",
            "firmware": 102,
            "last_upgrade": 1440006125,
            "wifi_status": 62,
            "friend_users": [
                "XXXX"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "mail": "XXX@XXX.XXX",
        "administrative": {
            "country": "DE",
            "reg_locale": "de-DE",
            "lang": "de-DE",
            "unit": 0,
            "windunit": 0,
            "pressureunit": 0,
            "feel_like_algo": 0
        }
    }
},
"status": "ok",
"time_exec": 0.050105810165405,
"time_server": 1483490016
}
```

In Windows it works just fine.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the JSON in question, so that we have a full [mcve]?

Comment: Just added the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have [raspbian](/questions/tagged/raspbian) to test, but from the traceback, it seems as though `JsonTextReader.ParseNumber()` may be parsing the number '-0.2' in a locale-specific culture (are you running in German, perhaps?) despite the fact that it explicitly tries to parse the number using the invariant culture, as is shown in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1859):

```
double value;
if (!double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
{
    throw ThrowReaderError("Input string '{0}' is not a valid number.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
}
```

Possibly you are using a forked version of Json.NET, or possibly there is some Mono bug on Raspbian, but either way the wrong culture seems to be getting used.

As a workaround, you could try to temporarily set the current culture to the invariant culture:

```
    Dim opts  = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() With { _
        .FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Double _
    }

    Dim myJSON as  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
    Dim oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    Try
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        myJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)(myStationJSON, opts)
    Finally
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture
    End Try
```

And, if that doesn't work, try running your exe using `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` as explained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/parsing-double-in-mono-c-fails), which seems to describe a similar problem.

Comment: Running my exe with "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" WORKS! Thank you so much!